# Print rotated css too short (IE / FF)

Tags: javascript, css, printing, cross-browser

I'm trying to rotate a wide table (work schedule, see example image below) for printing purposes. The reason I'm doing this is because I want the table to stretch over multiple pages so when you print it on paper you can put the different sheets together and get 1 decent sized, readable table/schedule. 
Now the problem I'm having isn't the rotating itself, it's the number of pages when trying to print the table. Instead of expanding the table to the next page it's cut-off so you'll only see the top part.
Now Google Chrome does the printing just fine, it spreads the table across 2 or 3 pages like I want it to. I'm having trouble however getting the same result in Firefox or IE.
I'm using the CSS `transform:rotate` method to rotate the body/schedule and get the wanted result in my browser (see below).

```
transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90eg);
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-o-transform:rotate(90deg);
```

I've tried adding margins, paddings to the table but it only moves the table around the page instead of expanding it to the next page. Adding overflow (`body *{ overflow:visible !important; }`) only scaled the body down so it'll fit on 1 page.

Is there any way to print this wide table on multiple pages so it's still readable for FF & IE?

Thanks in advance.

*Example image (usually there's text in the time-blocks):*
[image: Example image]
(Normal printing in landscape mode won't do because the text becomes too small to read.)

Comment: Why not leaving this to the user with portrait/landscape orientation?

Comment: Like I said... "Normal printing in landscape mode won't do because the text becomes too small to read"

Answer (score 0):

When you use a css rotation the actual dimensions don't change.

So if you have a block that is 100 x 20 px and you rotate it. The browser will still see the 100 x 20 px block, while you see a 20 x 100 block. Adding margins and padding's wont change this, you will need to modify the height and width.

I guess the simplest method would be to add an invisible div that has the same height as the tables width and vice versa. You can use javascript for this.

Comment: Makes sense, but sadly it doesn't work. Adding another div with a bigger height does add more pages, but only the newly added div is shown on those pages, not the table. Increasing the table's height adds rows on another page but not in the way I want it to (and the content is still cut off). Lets say there's a 5 row table and I increase the table's height, it displays 3 rows on the first page and 2 on the second page. I want all 5 rows displayed on both pages.

Comment: And wrapping the table in the new div? `<div><table>...</table></div>` with those properties?

Comment: Same result. It seems like the rotation isn't really a rotation, it merely shows the content rotated but doesn't actually rotate anything. So it still uses the height to decide the number of pages even though it should be using the width. It's pretty much the same as using landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: landscape;
  }
  div.landscape-parent {
    width: 585mm;
    height: 450mm;
  }

  div.landscape {
    width: 585mm;
    height: 450mm;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-585mm, 0);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    align-content: end;

  }

  div.content {
    padding: 10mm 10mm 10mm 10mm;
  }
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to leave also comments for the snippet. You could write a desciription before the code block or in the code as a comment.